# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Scala project

Tags: scala, mapreduce, akka

I built a MapReduce application and wrote it in Scala by using Akka Actor. I am trying to run 3 different JVMs in 3 Terminal Windows, one for my Client, and the other two for my remote Server (which I basically run on my localhost to simulate the distributed application). They can be compiled well. But when it comes to 'run', I saw the following exception. I am really bad at sbt and also new to Scala, Akka. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas about how to fix it?

[server side error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08dLG.png)

[client side error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWwOA.png)

Updated: Nevermind, it turns out I made a silly mistake by forgetting to delete my old package name after deleted the package folder.

Comment: Please click the link below for the error screenshots! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project structure and code for `Main` class ?

Comment: Thanks for asking the screenshot. Nevermind, it turns out that I forgot to delete my package name in each sub-file after I delete the package folder. Now, everything is working.